# Env variable in vscode defined through launch.json is not picked up when running spring boot application

Tags: spring-boot, environment-variables, vscode-debugger

My spring boot application is not picking up the env variables from .vscode launch.json when running the app, but when debugging, it is correctly picked up.
I have attached the relavent codes and logs, also please take a look at the project structure, i'm pretty new to setting up environments in vscode and so. help would be appreciate.

**application.yml**

```
security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          google:
            client-id: ${GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID}
            client-secret: ${GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET}
            redirectUri: http://localhost:8080/food-delivery/oauth2/callback/{registrationId}
            scope: openid,profile,email
          facebook:
            client-id: ${FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID}
            client-secret: ${FACEBOOK_CLIENT_SECRET}
            redirectUri: http://localhost:8080/food-delivery/oauth2/callback/{registrationId}
            scope: email,public_profile
          github:
            client-id: ${GITHUB_CLIENT_ID}
            client-secret: ${GITHUB_CLIENT_SECRET}
            redirectUri: http://localhost:8080/food-delivery/oauth2/callback/{registrationId}
            scope: read:user,user:email
```

**launch.json**

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "java",
            "name": "ServerApplication",
            "request": "launch",
            "mainClass": "com.solutions.computic.server.ServerApplication",
            "projectName": "server",
            "envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/server/.env"
        },
        {
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
            "url": "http://localhost:3000",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/client"
        }
    ]
}
```

**.env**

```
GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID=samplegoogleclientid
GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET=samplegoogleclientsecret
FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID=samplefacebookclientid
FACEBOOK_CLIENT_SECRET=samplefacebookclientsecret
GITHUB_CLIENT_ID=samplegithubclientid
GITHUB_CLIENT_SECRET=samplegithubclientsecret
```

**debug log**

```
PS D:\Personal_Projects\food-delivery>  ${env:GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID}='samplegoogleclientid'; ${env:GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET}='samplegoogleclientsecret'; ${env:FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID}='samplefacebookclientid'; ${env:FACEBOOK_CLIENT_SECRET}='samplefacebookclientsecret'; ${env:GITHUB_CLIENT_ID}='samplegithubclientid'; ${env:GITHUB_CLIENT_SECRET}='samplegithubclientsecret'; & 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\bin\java.exe' '-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=n,suspend=y,address=localhost:54694' '@C:\Users\MOHAME~1\AppData\Local\Temp\cp_bpuffhxq61ivg36jve44qdo7v.argfile' 'com.solutions.computic.server.ServerApplication' 

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.2.2)

2024-03-08T10:49:45.233+05:30  INFO 8548 --- [food-delivery] [           main] c.s.computic.server.ServerApplication    : Starting ServerApplication using Java 17.0.6 with PID 8548 (D:\Personal_Projects\food-delivery\server\target\classes started by MohamedNawas in D:\Personal_Projects\food-delivery)
2024-03-08T10:49:45.240+05:30  INFO 8548 --- [food-delivery] [           main] c.s.computic.server.ServerApplication    : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2024-03-08T10:49:46.246+05:30  INFO 8548 --- [food-delivery] [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2024-03-08T10:49:46.354+05:30  INFO 8548 --- [food-delivery] [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 96 ms. Found 2 JPA repository interfaces.
2024-03-08T10:49:47.159+05:30  INFO 8548 --- [food-delivery] [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port 8080 (http)
2024-03-08T10:49:47.180+05:30  INFO 8548 --- [food-delivery] [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2024-03-08T10:49:47.180+05:30  INFO 8548 --- [food-delivery] [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.18]
2024-03-08T10:49:47.265+05:30  INFO 8548 --- [food-delivery] [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/food-delivery]           : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2024-03-08T10:49:47.267+05:30  INFO 8548 --- [food-delivery] [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1969 ms
2024-03-08T10:49:47.309+05:30  INFO 8548 --- [food-delivery] [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2024-03-08T10:49:47.566+05:30  INFO 8548 --- [food-delivery] [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Added connection conn0: url=jdbc:h2:mem:fooddeliverydb?createDatabaseIfNotExists=true user=ROOT
2024-03-08T10:49:47.569+05:30  INFO 8548 --- [food-delivery] [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2024-03-08T10:49:47.586+05:30  INFO 8548 --- [food-delivery] [           main] o.s.b.a.h2.H2ConsoleAutoConfiguration    : H2 console available at '/h2-console'. Database available at 'jdbc:h2:mem:fooddeliverydb?createDatabaseIfNotExists=true'
2024-03-08T10:49:47.810+05:30  INFO 8548 --- [food-delivery] [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2024-03-08T10:49:47.914+05:30  INFO 8548 --- [food-delivery] [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 6.4.1.Final
2024-03-08T10:49:47.969+05:30  INFO 8548 --- [food-delivery] [           main] o.h.c.internal.RegionFactoryInitiator    : HHH000026: Second-level cache disabled
2024-03-08T10:49:48.300+05:30  INFO 8548 --- [food-delivery] [           main] o.s.o.j.p.SpringPersistenceUnitInfo      : No LoadTimeWeaver setup: ignoring JPA class transformer
2024-03-08T10:49:48.370+05:30  WARN 8548 --- [food-delivery] [           main] org.hibernate.orm.deprecation            : HHH90000025: H2Dialect does not need to be specified explicitly using 'hibernate.dialect' (remove the property setting and it will be selected by default)        
2024-03-08T10:49:49.484+05:30  INFO 8548 --- [food-delivery] [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000489: No JTA platform available (set 'hibernate.transaction.jta.platform' to enable JTA platform integration)
Hibernate: create table auth_details (id varchar(255) not null, email varchar(255) not null, name varchar(255) not null, pwd varchar(255), role_type varchar(255) check (role_type in ('ADMIN','USER')), primary key (id))
Hibernate: create table oauth2user (id varchar(255) not null, email varchar(255) not null, name varchar(255) not null, pwd varchar(255), role_type varchar(255) check (role_type in ('ADMIN','USER')), email_verified boolean, provider varchar(255) check (provider in ('GOOGLE','FACEBOOK','GITHUB')), provider_id varchar(255), primary key (id))
2024-03-08T10:49:49.585+05:30  INFO 8548 --- [food-delivery] [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2024-03-08T10:49:50.358+05:30  WARN 8548 --- [food-delivery] [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2024-03-08T10:49:50.851+05:30  INFO 8548 --- [food-delivery] [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Will secure any request with [org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@4b3e4253, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@13b5598b, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter@4c57ca10, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@1fc4b8d6, org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter@141c66db, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@7a57c5d9, org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter@40da1644, org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter@1e733bb5, com.solutions.computic.server.configs.filters.JwtAndLoginFilter@66ec4409, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter@6ae5e1cf, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter@18f794e, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@3fe21d0e, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@787b7796, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@389a9ff6, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@2dbc66f0, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@3cc2c4b8, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter@3fc2e100]
2024-03-08T10:49:51.174+05:30  INFO 8548 --- [food-delivery] [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port 8080 (http) with context path '/food-delivery'
2024-03-08T10:49:51.190+05:30  INFO 8548 --- [food-delivery] [           main] c.s.computic.server.ServerApplication    : Started ServerApplication in 6.356 seconds (process running for 6.889)
```

**Run log**

```
PS D:\Personal_Projects\food-delivery\server> mvn spring-boot:run
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] -------------------< com.solutions.computic:server >--------------------
[INFO] Building server 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> spring-boot-maven-plugin:3.2.2:run (default-cli) > test-compile @ server >>>
[WARNING] The artifact mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:8.0.33 has been relocated to com.mysql:mysql-connector-j:jar:8.0.33: MySQL Connector/J artifacts moved to reverse-DNS compliant Maven 2+ coordinates.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.3.1:resources (default-resources) @ server ---
[INFO] Copying 1 resource from src\main\resources to target\classes
[INFO] Copying 0 resource from src\main\resources to target\classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.11.0:compile (default-compile) @ server ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.3.1:testResources (default-testResources) @ server ---
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory D:\Personal_Projects\food-delivery\server\src\test\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.11.0:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ server ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] <<< spring-boot-maven-plugin:3.2.2:run (default-cli) < test-compile @ server <<<
[INFO]
[INFO]
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:3.2.2:run (default-cli) @ server ---
[INFO] Attaching agents: []

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.2.2)

2024-03-08T10:51:57.687+05:30  INFO 9048 --- [food-delivery] [           main] c.s.computic.server.ServerApplication    : Starting ServerApplication using Java 17.0.6 with PID 9048 (D:\Personal_Projects\food-delivery\server\target\classes started by MohamedNawas in D:\Personal_Projects\food-delivery\server)
2024-03-08T10:51:57.687+05:30  INFO 9048 --- [food-delivery] [           main] c.s.computic.server.ServerApplication    : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2024-03-08T10:51:58.428+05:30  INFO 9048 --- [food-delivery] [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2024-03-08T10:51:58.489+05:30  INFO 9048 --- [food-delivery] [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 57 ms. Found 2 JPA repository interfaces.
2024-03-08T10:51:59.042+05:30  INFO 9048 --- [food-delivery] [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port 8080 (http)
2024-03-08T10:51:59.052+05:30  INFO 9048 --- [food-delivery] [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2024-03-08T10:51:59.052+05:30  INFO 9048 --- [food-delivery] [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.18]
2024-03-08T10:51:59.097+05:30  INFO 9048 --- [food-delivery] [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/food-delivery]           : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2024-03-08T10:51:59.097+05:30  INFO 9048 --- [food-delivery] [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1342 ms
2024-03-08T10:51:59.137+05:30  INFO 9048 --- [food-delivery] [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2024-03-08T10:51:59.268+05:30  INFO 9048 --- [food-delivery] [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Added connection conn0: url=jdbc:h2:mem:fooddeliverydb?createDatabaseIfNotExists=true user=ROOT
2024-03-08T10:51:59.273+05:30  INFO 9048 --- [food-delivery] [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2024-03-08T10:51:59.273+05:30  INFO 9048 --- [food-delivery] [           main] o.s.b.a.h2.H2ConsoleAutoConfiguration    : H2 console available at '/h2-console'. Database available at 'jdbc:h2:mem:fooddeliverydb?createDatabaseIfNotExists=true'
2024-03-08T10:51:59.394+05:30  INFO 9048 --- [food-delivery] [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2024-03-08T10:51:59.438+05:30  INFO 9048 --- [food-delivery] [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 6.4.1.Final
2024-03-08T10:51:59.466+05:30  INFO 9048 --- [food-delivery] [           main] o.h.c.internal.RegionFactoryInitiator    : HHH000026: Second-level cache disabled
2024-03-08T10:51:59.656+05:30  INFO 9048 --- [food-delivery] [           main] o.s.o.j.p.SpringPersistenceUnitInfo      : No LoadTimeWeaver setup: ignoring JPA class transformer
2024-03-08T10:51:59.685+05:30  WARN 9048 --- [food-delivery] [           main] org.hibernate.orm.deprecation            : HHH90000025: H2Dialect does not need to be specified explicitly using 'hibernate.dialect' (remove the property setting and it will be selected by default)        
2024-03-08T10:52:00.337+05:30  INFO 9048 --- [food-delivery] [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000489: No JTA platform available (set 'hibernate.transaction.jta.platform' to enable JTA platform integration)
Hibernate: create table auth_details (id varchar(255) not null, email varchar(255) not null, name varchar(255) not null, pwd varchar(255), role_type varchar(255) check (role_type in ('ADMIN','USER')), primary key (id))
Hibernate: create table oauth2user (id varchar(255) not null, email varchar(255) not null, name varchar(255) not null, pwd varchar(255), role_type varchar(255) check (role_type in ('ADMIN','USER')), email_verified boolean, provider varchar(255) check (provider in ('GOOGLE','FACEBOOK','GITHUB')), provider_id varchar(255), primary key (id))
2024-03-08T10:52:00.386+05:30  INFO 9048 --- [food-delivery] [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2024-03-08T10:52:00.718+05:30  WARN 9048 --- [food-delivery] [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2024-03-08T10:52:00.952+05:30  INFO 9048 --- [food-delivery] [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Will secure any request with [org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@2be208db, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@5ed463b7, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter@550e7ef6, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@674d2b8b, org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter@1ae90cb9, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@401d83ce, org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter@496004e3, org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter@7a57c5d9, com.solutions.computic.server.configs.filters.JwtAndLoginFilter@5f726750, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter@37922937, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter@3b62c51e, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@58701e8c, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@951461a, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@7db679, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@1677f98b, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@3b72860c, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter@62b0792]
2024-03-08T10:52:01.115+05:30  INFO 9048 --- [food-delivery] [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port 8080 (http) with context path '/food-delivery'
2024-03-08T10:52:01.124+05:30  INFO 9048 --- [food-delivery] [           main] c.s.computic.server.ServerApplication    : Started ServerApplication in 3.772 seconds (process running for 4.118)
```

**Project structure**

```
food-delivery/
  |- .vscode/
     |- launch.json
  |- server/
     |- src/
        |- main/
           |- java/
              |- com/
                 |- solutions/
                    |- computic/
                       |- server/
                          |- ServerApplication.java
            |- resources/
                |- application.yml
     |- .env
```